# Alignment of Checkbox in the header of ultrawingrid

Tags: checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

[image: header align with checkboxes in the grid]

I am having an issue aligning the header checkbox with other checkboxes on an Infragistics UltraWinGrid. If I remove the label the header checkbox aligns with the center, but if I add ALL in the caption of header, it is not in alignment with other checkboxes... Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may set [HeaderCheckBoxAlignment](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~HeaderCheckBoxAlignment.html) property of the column header. You may use code like this in InitializeLayout event:

```
e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Header.CheckBoxAlignment = HeaderCheckBoxAlignment.Bottom;
```

Note, possible values for the Alignment are described [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.HeaderCheckBoxAlignment.html). If it is up to me I would go for Bottom or Top.

Comment: Hello...Thank you for the reply. If I align in top or bottom, the width of the column headings are increased, which should not be the case as I want them to be same width as other rows in the grid.